# Python: Coloring cells in FPDF is not working?

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf

I'm using the FPDF library to create a PDF, and I was looking to color the cells on my document. I looked through the API and found out that this is the way to do it:

```
fpdf.set_fill_color(r: int, g: int = -1, b: int = -1)
```

So I go ahead and do this in my script:

```
pdf = FPDF()

pdf.add_page()

pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 7)
pdf.set_fill_color(0, 0, 255)
pdf.cell(190, 6, 'Testing...', 1, 1, 'L')

pdf.output('Color.pdf', 'F')
```

And the color does not change. Everything else works fine, I just get a white cell instead of one that is colored blue. No errors are thrown either. Am I doing something wrong or is this PyFPDF malfunctioning?

EDIT: Added `pdf.add_page()` and `pdf.output('Color.pdf', 'F')` to this question (forgot to do it here, had it in my script).

Comment: @eyllanesc It did, thanks! I apologize for not responding earlier, it slipped my mind.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/cell/index.html) you must set the `fill` to `True`.

> [...]
>
> **fill:**
>
> Indicates if the cell background must be painted (`True`) or transparent
>   (`False`). Default value: `False`.
>
> [...]

---

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()

pdf.add_page()

pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 7)
pdf.set_fill_color(0, 0, 255)
pdf.cell(190, 6, 'Testing...', 1, 1, 'L', fill=True)

pdf.output('Color.pdf', 'F')
```

Comment: How to color a cell based on the value stored in that cell?

Comment: @Mainland check the value that will be on the cell, do your logic, pick a color, then call set_fill_color(), then call cell(), then reset to the color you like (or fill=False)

Answer (score 0):

This post helped me color my cells, thanks :)

However, I then stumbled upon the limitations that it only supports RGB and not RGBA for transparent/opaque coloring. Browsing around (mostly [here](https://py-pdf.github.io/fpdf2/fpdf/fpdf.html#fpdf.fpdf.FPDF.local_context) and [here](https://py-pdf.github.io/fpdf2/Transparency.html)), I was able to obtain RGBA colored cells by using the `local_context()` method along `rect()` and the `cell()` method. Here's a snippet:

```
# set your desired Alpha here, both fill and stroke supported
with pdf.local_context(fill_opacity=0.5, stroke_opacity=0.2):
    # set the desired color in RGB
    pdf.set_fill_color(250, 0, 250)
    # get current cursor position and draw rect there
    # use same dimensions as the cell, F for filled
    curr_x = pdf.get_x()
    curr_y = pdf.get_y()
    pdf.rect(curr_x, curr_y, 45, 15, 'F')

# finally, draw cell over the colored rect OUTSIDE the with    
pdf.cell(45, 15, "This is a RGBA Cell", 1, 0, 'C')
```